# Turn a string into array with PHP variables

Tags: php, arrays, eval

I have a string like this:

`$string = '[miniTrack, boxTrack]'`

I want to turn it into an array of variables like this:

`$array = [$miniTrack, $boxTrack]`;

So that I can perform loops and iterations through the variable.  And access the variables they are referencing.

I tried eval but I can't figure out how to convert it to a PHP Variable.

`I KNOW THAT THIS IS NOT IDEAL, THE STRUCTURE OF THE DATABASE THIS IS PULLING FROM CAN'T BE ADJUSTED UNFORTUNATELY`

Comment: Why you are using [] in strings?

Comment: Can you use $string = 'miniTrack, boxTrack';?

Comment: @KajaMydeen No unfortunately

Comment: you can't eval. that's not valid PHP code, because `minitrack` and `boxtrack` will be seen as undefined/unknown constants. YOu'll have to parse the string manually. explode on commas, strip off the `[]`, etc... And frankly, dynamically generating variable names is just a plain bad idea. it's pretty much always a sign of  bad design, and will make for insanely ugly code that's nearly impossible to figure out/maintain later on.

Comment: Okay. So you need those values as array? @Jordash

Comment: @KajaMydeen Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question starts unusually, because you show an array containing a single string that is comma-separated, rather than an array of individual strings.

You could try something like the following:

```
$arr = [];
$string = ['miniTrack, boxtrack'];
//split the one string into an array, trimming spaces
$vars= array_map('trim', explode(',', $string[0]));
foreach($vars as $var) {
    $arr[] = $var; //add the var to the array 
}

print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [0] => miniTrack
    [1] => boxtrack
)
```

And if you need to create a variable for each item, you can create "variable variables":

```
foreach($vars as $var) {
    $my_var = $$var; //variable variable
}
```

Comment: The `$$var` part isn't turning it into a variable

Comment: it's outputting as blank, but I think this is close

Comment: Nevermind I was doing the var wrong, this is working great!

Comment: I don't understand the `$my_var = $$var; //variable variable` though

Comment: @EdwardBlack http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php  - treats a string as the name of a variable. If `$x = 'test';` then `$xx` would be equivalent to a variable called `$test`

Comment: @rmirabelle thanks, so that means a new variable is defined with the name and value of the string?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as the following:

```
preg_match_all('~(\w+)~','[miniTrack, boxTrack]', $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $var)
{
    print $$var;    
}
```

Comment: Why do you print two $$ ?

Comment: if $var is miniTrack, $$var will be $miniTrack

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your strings to array like this. It may be not ideal but you can use try this.

```
$string = '[miniTrack, boxTrack]';
$string = str_replace(array('[',']'),array('', '' ), $string);
$array = explode(',',$string);
```

Here you can iterate your array whatever you want.